# You will starve when the inevitable occasional year arrives in which your one field has a low yield

Tags: relative-pronouns, antecedents

> It is not the peasant’s goal to produce the highest possible time‐averaged crop yield, averaged over many years. If your time‐averaged yield is marvelously high as a result of the combination of nine great years and one year of crop failure, you will still starve to death in that one year of crop failure before you can look back to congratulate yourself on your great time‐averaged yield. Instead, the peasant’s aim is to make sure to produce a yield above the starvation level in every single year, even though the time‐averaged yield may not be highest. That’s why field scattering may make sense. If you have just one big field, no matter how good it is on the average, you will starve when the inevitable occasional year arrives **in which** your one field has a low yield. But if you have many different fields, varying independently of each other, then in any given year some of your fields will produce well even when your other fields are producing poorly.<The World Until Yesterday, Jared Diamond · 2013>

I think the 'which' in "in which" or 'in which' itself is not grammatical or very rare because the antecedent is not a noun but a clause that includes the verb 'arrives'. Is the sentence 'you will starve when the inevitable occasional year arrives in which your one field has a low yield' grammatical or wrong?

Comment: But the antecedent of ***in which*** IS a noun. It's *the inevitable occasional **year***. Specifically, ***the*** year with a low yield. Though why the peasant wouldn't just put some money in the bank during the 9 good years, rather than buying up inefficient small parcels of land, escapes me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I doubt that banks existed in early agrarian societies, or if they did they weren't available to your average peasant!

Comment: It is completely grammatical. The year in which he arrived on these shores was 1655. For example.

Comment: @KateBunting: It was intended metaphorically. Put some stuff by - either long-term storage of your own food, or swap your surplus for a "delayed barter" with someone else who definitely *will* have food in those years when you need it. I just think *any* method of leveraging the resilience of society at large is better than encouraging a few people to start piecemeal hoovering up the land of those families that already went to the wall. Both approaches are "insurance", but Diamond's advice looks to me like it favours the "better off" over society at large. "Field scattering" is inefficient.

Comment: @Lambie Yeah, but my example includes 'arrives' before 'in which' and that was the question.

Comment: This is a case of **Extraposition from noun phrase movement**. When you have a subject noun phrase with a long relative clause, and a short verb phrase like the one-word verb phrase "*arrives*", we can detach the relative clause from the subject and put it at the end of the clause. That is what has happened here. The long relative clause "*in which your one field has a low yield*" belongs with the nominal "inevitable occasional year." However, because the verb phrase "*arrives*" is so short, it has jumped over it and appears at the end of the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

I add to what @FumbleFingers has explained about the antecedent.

> ...you will starve when the inevitable occasional year arrives in which your one field has a low yield.

is fine.

*which* modifies *year*.

That clause means the same as

> ...you will starve when the inevitable occasional year in which your one field has a low yield **arrives**.

This latter version, however, has a long adjective between the noun and the verb, and is hence not preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Relative pronouns do not need to immediately follow their antecedents. It's even possible for several nouns to come between the antecedent and the relative pronoun without causing confusion.

To find the antecedent of a relative pronoun, look back in the sentence to the first noun that matches the relative clause grammatically and semantically:

> There's a car in that field past the wall of stone which hasn't been driven for 50 years.

In that sentence, "which" unambiguously refers to "car" even though the two aren't beside each other, and even though "stone", "wall" and "fence" are closer.